# With onclick show hidden div in other html file

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I use Javascript and 'onclick' to show hidden div's in a large database, when I use onclick it shows as a popup. It works fine in the same html-file, but I cannot get an id openend in another html file. How can I do this?

I use this javascript code (sh = show):

```
 var divState = {}; function sh(id) {
if (document.getElementById) {
    var divid = document.getElementById(id);
divState[id] = (divState[id]) ? false : true;
 //close others
 for (var div in divState){
    if (divState[div] && div != id){
        document.getElementById(div).style.visibility = 'hidden';
        divState[div] = false;
    }
}
divid.style.visibility = (divid.style.visibility == 'visible' ? 'hidden' : 'visible'); } }
```

And I call the item with this code (id=1):

```
 <a class=w onclick="sh('1');">asdfasdf asdasdfds</a>
```

I tried `<a onclick="window.location.href='../A/index.html?id=0174' ">` but it does not "open" or rather show id=0174, only opens index.html in the A-directory. How can I make id 0174 in A/index.html visible when clicked on some item in E/index.html?

Many thanks!

Comment: You can create a js file and embed this script in both html files.

Comment: But that does not show the hidden div in the other html-file.

Comment: Can you describe your workflow? What do you mean with other html file? Do you mean like two open tabs and if you change something on tab1, tab2 should also change something?

Comment: I have separate html files, index.html in different folders (directories). Folder A ... Z For each letter of the alphabet a folder with a index.html with items, alphabetically ordered. Each item is a div with an id. Each index.html file has the same javascript, embed is an option but does not add much to solving the issue at hand. As this is to be a special kind of encyclopaedia, I have to make cross-references.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) CSS pseudo-class to show or hide elements with the id specified as the hash in the url.

For example: `<a href="../A/index.html#0174">Link to div #0174 on other page</a>`

```css
.show-when-target {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.show-when-target:target {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="1" class="show-when-target">
  Hello from div 1!
</div>

<div id="2" class="show-when-target">
  Hello from div 2!
</div>

<div id="3" class="show-when-target">
  Hello from div 3!
</div>

<a href="#1">Show Div 1</a>
<a href="#2">Show Div 2</a>
<a href="#3">Show Div 3</a>
```

Comment: I cannot use this as I have on purpose not used `display:block` for it does not work for the disabled, the blind users of the web. I understand making use of `visibility:visible` does not impair readability.

Comment: There's no reason why you couldn't use `visibility` instead. Updated the snippet.

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but did not work. Perhaps I should have mentioned that the invisible div is a child of the parent div. Real code looks like this: `<div class=w onclick="sh('1');">Etna</div><div class=tt id=1><a onclick="sh('1');">Etna</a> Een actieve vulkaan in het noordoosten van Sicilië, bla bla </div>` I had to repeat subject Etna to have it visible again in the popup with explanation. The first Etna is the subject of a long list of items with extra information. No, I am wrong, it is not a child, it was so at the start, but I changed that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do there. Why are you calling `sh()` on click of the `div` and on click of the `a`? Also, why does the child `div` have id 1 if that's the id you're trying to show in the other page?

Comment: I use the second onclick to close the popup window when reading of its contents is done. It was opened, made visible, by clicking on a long list of subjects with class=w. One could also click on another subject to get this window closed, but sometimes the popup window hovers over many other subjects and there is no other way to close this window, or I would have to expand javascript but since I am not adept in js I used this option. Furthermore I found it neat not to use a closing x in one of the corners of the popup-window. Hope this makes sense.